# Create columns without rows (remove blank space below one section)

Tags: html, css

So I already tried Google for this problem, but couldn't find a solution. I'm currently trying to divide my page in to 50% columns. The left column should contain an image and a form, the right one a text description (with a variable size).
I want the sections of the first column, to not be affected by the ones in the second one, so the same logic as `column-count` would use. If I use `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;` to create my columns and I adjust the browser window, the text in the right column gets longer and pushes down the form under the image, which creates a blank space. 
Is there any way using `grid-template-columns` and not having the content of both related to each other, so there are only two columns and the spacing between each item just stays the same when resizing the browser window?

Forgot to mention that when the browser window gets resized, two columns should merge to one and the order of the sections should be image, text, form. Is there a way to adapt the order when resized?

CSS code used:

```
.grid-custom{
  padding-left: $grid-gutter;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: $grid-gutter;


  @include media-query($small) {
    padding-left: $grid-gutter-mobile;
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-mobile;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what are the implementation that you made?

Comment: I can only post the CSS since the html is pretty large. But I use a <div class="grid-custom"> for the whole site which includes a picture, text, and a form.
CSS
`.grid-custom{
  padding-left: $grid-gutter;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: $grid-gutter;
  
  
  @include media-query($small) {
    padding-left: $grid-gutter-mobile;
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-mobile;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}`

Comment: Update your question please, so that it will be easy for us to test.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not have to be large to display the concept.
Consider this:

```css
 * { box-sizing: border-box; }
 .layout-wrap {
   display: flex;
   min-height: calc(1px  +  40vw);
 }
 .div1 { margin-right: 0.5em; }
 .div1, .div2 { width: 50%; border: 4px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="layout-wrap">
  <div class="div1"> <h1>IMAGE &amp; FORM</h1> </div>
  <div class="div2"> <h1>TEXT</h1> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would probably work like this, but I forgot to mention that in mobile view, the order of the sections should be the following (image, description, form). So is there a way to change the order when put in mobile view?

Comment: Can you expand upon your request?  How is the display to look on desktop or laptop versus tablet or phone?  Have you investigated using the 'media' commands of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any CSS for  50%-50% screen or media query if u use this

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="border col-sm-6">
              <div> 
                  <img src="sample.jpg">

              </div>
              <div>
                  <h2>Contact us</h2>
                  <form >
                    First name:
                    <input type="text" name="firstname">
                    <br><br>
                    Last name:
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" >
                    <br><br>
                    Email ID:
                    <input type="email" name="email" >
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </form> 
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="border col-sm-6">
               <h1>hello</h1>
               <h2>hello</h2>
               <h3>hello</h3>
               <h4>hello</h4>
               <h5>hello</h5>
               <h6>hello</h6>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the order of the sections should be different when resized. So for mobile, instead of image, form, text, it should be image, text, form, all in one column. Is it possible to change the order when resized?

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` you can achieve this. Please refer snippet below for css part.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.col1{
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.col2{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.form{  
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
       
       <div class="form">
         Name: <input type="text"><br>
         Class: <input type="text"><br>
         Roll No: <input type="text">
       </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel odio non felis consectetur consectetur ut in felis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis cursus metus. Nulla ligula purus, pellentesque eu dignissim fermentum, finibus nec mi. Curabitur sapien ex, dignissim eu accumsan sollicitudin, semper sed risus. Mauris pulvinar nisi quis semper interdum. Ut eu hendrerit felis, a gravida neque. Donec tincidunt quam et justo tincidunt tincidunt. Donec in quam tempus, tempus erat vel, fringilla lectus. Nullam iaculis non ipsum sodales varius. Etiam sagittis egestas orci non aliquet. Sed venenatis sodales sem, ut ultrices lacus dapibus quis. Curabitur volutpat libero eget volutpat ornare. Phasellus condimentum laoreet risus ultrices vulputate. Vestibulum dignissim ipsum et leo interdum varius. Maecenas vehicula enim id massa tincidunt scelerisque.

Sed diam nisi, aliquet eu massa non, tempor vehicula libero. Nam nec bibendum augue, nec eleifend orci. Quisque efficitur volutpat dui id semper. Duis ac mi leo. Donec eget suscipit ex, suscipit finibus nulla. Sed convallis enim vel lorem porttitor tincidunt. Etiam convallis facilisis urna. Nullam viverra tempor metus, ac pellentesque massa sodales sit amet. Maecenas sed consequat elit, ut volutpat arcu. Nam dui mi, vestibulum ut enim id, fermentum tempor lorem. Nunc eleifend, magna lobortis blandit pulvinar, justo tellus placerat lorem, in venenatis augue velit vel neque.

Donec fermentum cursus urna ut mattis. Fusce tincidunt augue volutpat, molestie dolor ac, vehicula dolor. Duis ante orci, pulvinar sit amet tincidunt volutpat, malesuada et urna. Suspendisse at hendrerit neque. Nullam vel varius tellus. Morbi sed sapien at nisl consequat interdum. Mauris quis odio id nulla suscipit feugiat sit amet et leo. Vivamus viverra pellentesque ligula at aliquam. Sed quis massa ullamcorper, ullamcorper turpis quis, tempus lorem. Sed quis nunc fermentum, commodo ante et, pulvinar tortor. Donec tincidunt sagittis nibh nec consectetur. Proin facilisis pretium mi, vitae pharetra neque sollicitudin at. Etiam condimentum odio id tortor finibus, eget porttitor mi aliquam. Vestibulum vulputate tincidunt tortor nec volutpat. Phasellus ut est risus. Sed convallis quis libero id congue.

Sed tempus, dui a sodales ullamcorper, lorem nunc varius lectus, nec sollicitudin mi leo eu mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris quis porttitor ante. Donec tincidunt molestie nunc posuere maximus. Praesent rhoncus cursus sem. Sed vitae vulputate urna. Morbi nec purus sit amet enim pharetra eleifend at eget nisi. Aliquam feugiat sodales massa, ut aliquet magna. Mauris justo metus, mollis ac porta ut, molestie hendrerit dolor. Mauris sed est interdum, feugiat eros eu, vehicula odio.

Vivamus lorem nibh, accumsan eget nibh efficitur, aliquam volutpat metus. Sed id dolor eget nisi ultricies tempor et blandit lectus. Fusce id ipsum at est congue ultrices. Sed id rutrum mi. Suspendisse semper justo ac metus finibus, vitae accumsan leo sagittis. Aliquam quis elit dolor. Morbi et tellus venenatis, imperdiet elit ac, semper augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ullamcorper porta lectus, in ullamcorper eros scelerisque ut. Sed id odio sit amet dolor vulputate finibus vel non dolor. Praesent orci lorem, porta sit amet turpis molestie, volutpat vestibulum felis. Phasellus non orci aliquet, vulputate risus in, tempor mi.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the order of the sections should be different when resized. So for mobile, instead of image, form, text, it should be image, text, form, all in one column. Is it possible to change the order when resized?

Comment: @Sacha I don't think it is possible to change the order in above solution.

Comment: So is there any other way figuring it out?